# ISTIO fails when host specified and HTTP redirect is enabled

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I am using ISTIO and hostnames to load balance and direct traffic. I have the following Virtual Service enabled:

```
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: app-lab-app
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  gateways:
    - istio-system/ingressgateway
  hosts:
    - hostname1.lab
  http:
  - match:
    route:
    - destination:
        host: search-head-service
        port:
          number: 8000
```

When I try to reach this service via cURL, I receive the following error (32271 is the hostport which is mapped to port 80 on ingressgateway):

```
curl -Hhost:hostname1.lab http://10.20.1.108:32271/ -L
curl: (7) Failed to connect to hostname1.lab port 80: Connection refused
```

**The issue is this..the endpoint does a redirect.  I can reach the first website, but once the redirect happens, it fails**

I can make this work by removing the hostname in the spec and changing to '*' but this won't help me do the host-based load balancing.

EDIT: ingress-gateway config (kubectl describe pod/ingress-gateway-xxxx)

```
Name:         istio-ingressgateway-657df8bc75-cmghw
Namespace:    istio-system
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-10-20-1-108.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.20.1.108
Start Time:   Tue, 21 Apr 2020 13:22:48 -0500
Labels:       app=istio-ingressgateway
              chart=gateways
              heritage=Tiller
              istio=ingressgateway
              pod-template-hash=657df8bc75
              release=istio
              service.istio.io/canonical-name=istio-ingressgateway
              service.istio.io/canonical-revision=1.5
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.192.1.36/32
              kubernetes.io/psp: 00-privileged
              sidecar.istio.io/inject: false
Status:       Running
IP:           10.192.1.36
IPs:
  IP:           10.192.1.36
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/istio-ingressgateway-657df8bc75
Containers:
  istio-proxy:
    Container ID:  docker://bfa29df838cd1e42a24674838bbf8454c8d56ec898b1833563f1b89a19a38030
    Image:         docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.5.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://docker.io/istio/proxyv2@sha256:89b5fe2df96920189a193dd5f7dbd776e00024e4c1fd1b59bb53867278e9645a
    Ports:         15020/TCP, 80/TCP, 443/TCP, 15029/TCP, 15030/TCP, 15031/TCP, 15032/TCP, 31400/TCP, 15443/TCP, 15011/TCP, 8060/TCP, 853/TCP, 15090/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 80/TCP, 443/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      proxy
      router
      --domain
      $(POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
      --proxyLogLevel=warning
      --proxyComponentLogLevel=misc:error
      --log_output_level=default:info
      --drainDuration
      45s
      --parentShutdownDuration
      1m0s
      --connectTimeout
      10s
      --serviceCluster
      istio-ingressgateway
      --zipkinAddress
      zipkin.istio-system:9411
      --proxyAdminPort
      15000
      --statusPort
      15020
      --controlPlaneAuthPolicy
      NONE
      --discoveryAddress
      istio-pilot.istio-system.svc:15012
      --trust-domain=cluster.local
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 21 Apr 2020 13:22:50 -0500
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      10m
      memory:   40Mi
    Readiness:  http-get http://:15020/healthz/ready delay=1s timeout=1s period=2s #success=1 #failure=30
    Environment:
      JWT_POLICY:                   first-party-jwt
      PILOT_CERT_PROVIDER:          istiod
      ISTIO_META_USER_SDS:          true
      CA_ADDR:                      istio-pilot.istio-system.svc:15012
      NODE_NAME:                     (v1:spec.nodeName)
      POD_NAME:                     istio-ingressgateway-657df8bc75-cmghw (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:                istio-system (v1:metadata.namespace)
      INSTANCE_IP:                   (v1:status.podIP)
      HOST_IP:                       (v1:status.hostIP)
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT:               (v1:spec.serviceAccountName)
      ISTIO_META_WORKLOAD_NAME:     istio-ingressgateway
      ISTIO_META_OWNER:             kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/istio-system/deployments/istio-ingressgateway
      ISTIO_META_MESH_ID:           cluster.local
      ISTIO_AUTO_MTLS_ENABLED:      true
      ISTIO_META_POD_NAME:          istio-ingressgateway-657df8bc75-cmghw (v1:metadata.name)
      ISTIO_META_CONFIG_NAMESPACE:  istio-system (v1:metadata.namespace)
      ISTIO_META_ROUTER_MODE:       sni-dnat
      ISTIO_META_CLUSTER_ID:        Kubernetes
    Mounts:
      /etc/istio/ingressgateway-ca-certs from ingressgateway-ca-certs (ro)
      /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs from ingressgateway-certs (ro)
      /etc/istio/pod from podinfo (rw)
      /var/run/ingress_gateway from ingressgatewaysdsudspath (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/istio from istiod-ca-cert (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from istio-ingressgateway-service-account-token-7ssdg (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  istiod-ca-cert:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      istio-ca-root-cert
    Optional:  false
  podinfo:
    Type:  DownwardAPI (a volume populated by information about the pod)
    Items:
      metadata.labels -> labels
      metadata.annotations -> annotations
  ingressgatewaysdsudspath:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  ingressgateway-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  istio-ingressgateway-certs
    Optional:    true
  ingressgateway-ca-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  istio-ingressgateway-ca-certs
    Optional:    true
  istio-ingressgateway-service-account-token-7ssdg:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  istio-ingressgateway-service-account-token-7ssdg
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  istio-ingressgateway=true
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Comment: Hi, did You check `ingressgateway` logs? Also use `curl` with `-v` flag for more information.

Comment: additional, could you add the gateway configuration?

Answer (score 0):

While I'd still like to understand what was happening originally, an ISTIO guru had me apply the patch below. These steps create an ISTIO Gateway (not an ingress gateway) on all nodes with the appropriate label:

Step 1 - Label certain nodes:

```
kubectl label nodes <hostname> istio-ingressgateway=true
kubectl label nodes <hostname> istio-ingressgateway=true
```

Step 2 - Save patch to a file like patch.json:

```
   "spec": {
      "replicas": 2,
      "template": {
         "spec": {
            "nodeSelector": {"istio-ingressgateway" : "true"},
            "containers": [
               {"name" : "istio-proxy", "ports": [{"containerPort" : 80, "hostPort" : 80, "protocol": "TCP"}, {"containerPort":443, "hostPort": 443, "protocol" : "TCP"}]}
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Step 3 - Apply the patch:

```
kubectl -n istio-system patch deployment/istio-ingressgateway --patch "$(cat patch.json)"
```